# Fading image using java1.1

Tags: java, awt

I need to fade the images using low level AWT classes for Set top boxes.It doesnt have any advanced classes.Does anyone know how I can do this (Java 1.1)??

Comment: Java 1.1 ? Are you sure?

Comment: @VanajaGoud, What backwards company do you work for?

Comment: Are you sure that a device running Java 1.1 has enough CPU/GPU power and RAM for a smooth fading of images?

Comment: Do you want a gradual fade over time, or do you just want to toggle between normal and faded?

Comment: +1 simply for the extraordinary requirement of Java 1.1

Comment: @rob i want to toggle between normal and faded

Comment: @VanajaGoud thanks for the clarification; that probably simplifies the solution and means processing power shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you could just increment/decrement the image transparency over a length of time?